# Discord OAuth returns missing "code in request

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to use a simple example to fetch an access token from the Discord API. I have the authorization code, but I'm struggling on exchanging it for the access token.

My code so far:

```
const code = **my authorization code**;
const CLIENT_ID = **my client id**;
const CLIENT_SECRET = **my client secret**;
const creds = btoa(`${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`);
fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${redirect}`,
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${creds}`,
  },
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((body) => console.log(body));
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
{
   error: 'invalid_request',
   error_description: 'Missing "code" in request.'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know how to fix this. So Discord API has been updated, you can no longer specify the code, grant type & redirect URI in the URL. You need to remove it from the URL and put it in the body.

This should fix it: https://sourceb.in/BGWsbUzope

Comment: If I do this, I just get "invalid_grant" error.   "{ error: 'invalid_grant' }"

Comment: Oh my bad, instead of using the JSON notation thing, use querystring npm module.

Comment: Which module is that? I've never heard of it.

Comment: It is called `querystring` on NPM.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring

Use this instead of JSON. So instead of JSON.stringify, it is querystring.stringify.

Comment: I still get the invalid_grant error. fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${creds}`,
      },
      body: querystring.stringify({
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((body) => console.log(body));

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to tell you, you need to set the Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Sorry to ask you again, but I get another error. "{ redirect_uri: [ 'Not a well formed URL.' ] }".

Comment: Can you send me your code? The full code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226995/discussion-between-satvikvejendla-and-xoalone).

Comment: Did you understand it? I have a feeling it has something to do with my Redirect URIs specified in the Discord Developer Portal, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Read the chat in the link u sent

Comment: can you please add the complete solution to the answer so everybody with this problem (like me) has a chance to solve it?